# Bar button Item enabling problems in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

All,

In ViewDidLoad , I have set :

```
BarButtonPAY.enabled = false
```

and that disables the bar button item and it is not selectable, thats fine.

I have an computed property on the View Controller, which enables the button with enable = true.

I am getting the error 'found nil in optional value' and I noticed that BarButtonItem is an optional. When I put the ? at the end of the variable it still does not enable. any ideas ?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var BarButtonPAY: UIBarButtonItem!

    var PayButton : Int {
        didSet {
                println("Barracuda")
                    BarButtonPAY?.enabled = true
        }
    }
```

I have set the computed property differently now in the view controller - like so (removed the var from init).

```
@IBOutlet weak var BarButtonPAY: UIBarButtonItem!

    var PayButton : Int? {
        didSet {
            println("Barracuda")
            BarButtonPAY?.enabled = true
        }
    }


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      //  self.PayButton = 0
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init() {
       // self.PayButton = 0
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    }
```

When the button is pressed on the tableview cell. To select a product, and highlight the pay button as a BarButtonItem :

```
@IBAction func SelectedButton(sender: UIButton) {


    // Set the colours and then highlight 'Next' on
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    sender.setTitle("Ordered", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    let test = ViewController()
    test.PayButton = 2

}
```

Comment: seems reasonable, how can  I fix ? the button is set in interface builder. I have a container on the view controller (with a tableview in it) , and when a button is pressed on a cell, it should call this computer variable (and it does).

Comment: You can first show your code where you set the computed property and present the view controller.

Comment: i think button comes from storyBoard, check button connection(delegate) storyBoard to ViewController and use like that in code BarButtonPAY!.enabled = true

Comment: And still, add the code where you show the view controller and access the `PayButton` property.

Answer (score 1):

Since PayButton is not an optional property I assume that you are setting its value in initializer before BarButtonPAY is initialized. Try setting a default value to PayButton

```
var PayButton : Int = -1 {
    didSet {
            println("Barracuda")
                BarButtonPAY?.enabled = true
    }
}
```

or declare it as optional Int

```
var PayButton : Int? {
    didSet {
            println("Barracuda")
                BarButtonPAY?.enabled = true
    }
}
```

and remove the line when you set its value on init on both cases

Edited

Even after creating object typed ViewController in `let test = ViewController()` BarButtonPAY is not initialized (you can not use it until ViewController viewDidLoad method). A possible workaround : create another optional Integer property in ViewController and name it lets say initialValue. On selectedButton set initialValue as follow

```
@IBAction func SelectedButton(sender: UIButton) {


// Set the colours and then highlight 'Next' on
sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
sender.setTitle("Ordered", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

let test = ViewController()
test.initialValue = 2

}
```

then in ViewController viewDidLoad set PayButton to initialValue

```
override func viewDidLoad(){

    PayButton = initialValue
}
```

Comment: I have removed the var in the init and I add -1 directly and still does not work

Comment: Where do you set it other places?

Comment: Maybe you are setting in in prepareForSegue of RootViewController?

Comment: Then are you sure that BarButtonPAY is connected correctly from storyboard (check the referencing outlets)? And please can you show me code when you set PayButton a value (wherever in your code)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79770/discussion-between-zellb-and-jason).

Answer (score 0):

When you do this `let test = ViewController()` you are creating a new instance of your view controller. This way your outlets will be `nil`. Try accessing your view controller from storyboard:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourViewController") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And then access the property:

```
viewController.PayButton = 2
```

Comment: this doesn't work because the class I am using to add a value to PayButton has not got ViewController delegate so 'presentViewController' is not valid.

Comment: I agree that the objects have gone out of the view hierarchy - I just need to connect to the view controller in a way that the objects don't disappear.